# Posting form string to php - causes mysql_real_escape_string() to break

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have a form with a hidden field that looks something like this:

```
     <form id="myform" method="post" action="/myphp.php">

        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="title" value="Bob's Group (test)" />
        </div>
        <div>     
            <input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="send_button" />
        </div>   


      </form>
```

The hidden value 'title' get's its value from a Perch CMS php inline script and in this case it's "Bob's Group (test)".

The php script to process this form looks like this:

```
<?php

// Get and check input
$title = check_input($_POST['title']);
echo "title: $title<br>";

$name = check_input($_POST['name']);

$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);

// Some sql queries that use $title
?>
```

The output looks like this:

title: Bob's Group (test)
title:

In other words, mysql_real_escape_string causes title to become a blank string.

Is there a way to handle this form value and generate a safe sql string to use?

Comment: Use prepared statements and do not use `mysql_*` for new code. `mysqli_*` or PDO is the way to take now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` is MySQL server-side. It requires an active DB connection. Check if you have one in the moment of check.

Just a note, not an advice: `mysql_escape_string()` is client-side, i.e. works in PHP even without active MySQL connection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have an active connection to MySQL for msyql_real_escape_string() to work. You're most likely getting back a boolean FALSE from m_r_e_s() because you haven't connected, and it's issuing an error. If you do

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title) or die(msyql_error());
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

you'll most likely get a "not connected" error message.

The connection is required so m_r_e_s can properly escape things - it basically asks the server what its must-be-escaped metacharacters are so it can do its job properly.